# variable number of match in a regexp

Tags: regex, string, tcl

I have this file :

```
#2/1/1/21=p1 5/1/1/21=p1 isid=104
3/1/1/9=p1 4/1/1/4=p1 5/1/1/17=p1 6/1/1/4=p1 isid=100
1/1/1/4=p1 6/1/1/5=p1 isid=101
```

I want line 1 to be ignored (it a commented line)
In line two I want to get "3/1/1/9" "4/1/1/4" "5/1/1/17" in three variables var1 var2 and var3
In line three I want to get "1/1/1/4" and "6/1/1/5" in two variables var1 and var2.

For the moment I can ignore line 1, and match what I want on line 2 OR line 3 :

```
if {[regexp {^(\d/\d/\d/\d{1,2})=p1.*(\d/\d/\d/\d{1,2})=p1} $line value match1 match2]} {  
    # This works for line 3 but not line 2
}

 if {[regexp {^(\d/\d/\d/\d{1,2})=p1.*(\d/\d/\d/\d{1,2})=p1.*(\d/\d/\d/\d{1,2})=p1} $line value match1 match2 match3]} {  
    # This works for line 2 but not line 3
}
```

How can I have the right number of matched for line 2 AND 3 ?

Comment: Are you checking line by line or on the file as a whole?

Comment: I am checking line by line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
[regexp {^(\d/\d/\d/\d{1,2})=p1.*?(\d/\d/\d/\d{1,2})=p1(?:.*?(\d/\d/\d/\d{1,2})=p1)?} $line value match1 match2 match3]
                                                       ^^^                        ^^
```

This makes the third match optional.

I also turned your greedy `.*` into non-greedy `.*?`.

---

To get all matches, you could use something more like this:

```
if {[string range $line 0 0] ne "#"} {
    set matches [regexp -all -inline -- {\d/\d/\d/\d{1,2}(?==p1)} $line]
}
```

And you will get the matches in the list `$matches`. You can then access them through `lindex` or if you use `lassign` and give them specific names.

Comment: It does not match anything with this, but I feel it's pretty close. I've been looking for this optional match for long !

Comment: @emmasculateur You sure this doesn't match anything? [See this codepad](http://codepad.org/JAbnNBxd).

Comment: So sorry, it DOES match, I just added an unexpected bracket in my copy/paste operation...

Comment: @emmasculateur It's okay, typos happen and when they do, programmers are the ones who have it the worst ;)

Comment: @emmasculateur By the way, [these](http://regex101.com/r/mG8cN0) are the values that you get with the question you asked. If you want to get _all_ the numbers, you'll have to use additional tools besides regex as it'll easily get out of hand.

Comment: Thanks for this _very_ useful link. I just saw that I actually needed a 4th match, line 2. So I added `(?:.*?(\d/\d/\d/\d{1,2})=p1)?`, and it seems to work [here](http://regex101.com/r/aE6rJ5) but not [here](http://codepad.org/QajBCzTn).

Comment: @emmasculateur Hmm, well that's weird... It works if you do this however: [link](http://codepad.org/xzOuEfKj).

Answer (score 1):

This might be better:

```
lassign [regexp -all -inline {\d+(?:/\d+){3}(?==p1)} $line] var1 var2 var3
```

If there are only 2 matches, var3 will be empty

If there are more matches, only the first 3 will be captured in variables.

If you really just want all the matches:

```
set vars [regexp -all -inline {\d+(?:/\d+){3}(?==p1)} $line]
```

---

To ignore comments:

```
while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
    if {[regexp {^\s*#} $line]} continue

    # do your other stuff here ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
(^|\s)(\d/\d/\d/\d=p1)
```

or more compactly:

```
(^|\s)((\d/){3}\d=p1)
```

Comment: It will match for line 1 also

Comment: @emmasculateur yes, I thought you said you were ignoring line 1? I will make an edit.

Comment: with this, it only takes the first match, not the second and the eventual third.

Comment: @emmasculateur strange…it matches all of them on my machine.  I will look into this..